# Value from query string not seen in twig output

Tags: symfony, twig, query-string, drupal-8

I have a working Drupal 8 site with the following in THEME.theme:

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $vars['get']['vguid'] = \Drupal\Component\Utility\XSS::filter($_GET['vguid']);
}
```

If I add the same line to THEME_preprocess_page() I get "Undefined index: in 'THEME_preprocess_page' when I attempt page loads.

In the the twig I have `{{ get.vguid }}`  and have also tried `{{ app.request.parameter.get("vguid") }}`

In the twigs (after cache is cleared) I get no value when page is accessed like `/mobile-video?vguid=15991b1f-2ad2-11e7-8da8-22000aeb1f8b`

How do I get a sanitized query string value into my twig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this and I had no problems:

```
function THEME_preprocess_TEMPLATE(&$variables)
{
    $variables['query__param'] = XSS::filter($_GET['keys']);
}
```

In your function you are using `$vars` and defining `$variables` as a parameter, maybe you should change that? `$vars['get']['vguid']` => `$variables['get']['vguid']`

Comment: Argh my stupidity hurts...  Why is index undefined?  Cause I pass $variables and try to add to $vars...  Thank you!  Accepting as soon as SO allows...

Comment: @jerrygarciuh it happens to everyone :) glad to help!

Answer (score -1):

```
{{ app.request.query.get("vguid") }}
```